# If $A$ is an abelian C*-algebra, and $\tau$ is pure then it is a character on $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

If  $A$ is an abelian C*-algebra,and positive linear functional $\tau$ is pure then it is a character on $A$.
Murphy in his book(C*-algebras and operator theory) has below proof:[image]

While I think we can do it more easier:

Let $\tau$ be pure. Since $A$ is abelian, $\phi_\tau(A)\subset \phi_\tau(A)'$. Also $\phi_\tau(A)'=\Bbb C 1$, so $\phi_\tau(A) \subset \Bbb C 1$ which shows that $$\tau(a)\tau(b)= \langle \phi_\tau(a)x_\tau,x_\tau\rangle\langle \phi_\tau(b)x_\tau,x_\tau\rangle =\langle \phi_\tau(ab)x_\tau,x_\tau\rangle =\tau(ab) $$for $a,b\in A$.

I do not know why murphy shows $B(H) = \Bbb C 1$ and then using whole $B(H)$ to show $\tau$ is multiplicative. Is my argument correct? or Is necessary to follow Murphy's argument? Thanks.

Comment: It's basically the same argument, you just showed less steps, no? Murphy showed something a little more general, which while not necessary, is still nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

I have just copied and pasted from my own notes on Murphy (*my comments in italic*). Hopefully something here is helpful!

Assume now that $A$ is abelian.

If $\rho$ is pure, then $\varphi_\rho(A)'=\mathbb{C}1_{H_\rho}$. But $\varphi_\rho(A)\subset \varphi(A)'$, so $\varphi_\rho(A)$ consists of scalars, and therefore $ B(H_\rho)\subset \varphi_\rho(A)'$

*I don't agree with this --- however, if $\rho$ is pure, then $(H_\rho,\varphi_\rho)$ is irreducible so that $\varphi_\rho$ has no invariant subspace of $H_\rho$. We want to prove that $B(H_\rho)=\mathbb{C}1_{H_\rho}$ --- i.e. that $H_\rho$ is one dimensional. Suppose on the contrary that $ H_\rho$ is not one dimensional --- in which case it has a two dimensional subspace with basis vectors $\{e_1,e_2\}$. However $\varphi_\rho(A)e_i\subset e_i$ as all of the $ \varphi_\rho(A)$ are scalars and this is a contradiction as $\varphi_\rho(A)$ acts irreducibly.*

Hence, $B(H_\rho)=\mathbb{C}I_{H_\rho}$. Therefore, if $T,\,S\in B(H_\rho)$ they are scalars and (using the fact that $x_\rho$ is a unit vector and looking at $\langle \lambda \mu x_\rho,x_\rho\rangle=\langle \lambda x_\rho,x_\rho\rangle\langle\mu x_\rho,x_\rho\rangle$) it is clear $\rho(ab)=\rho(a)\rho(b)$ and therefore a character on $A$.

Now suppose conversely that $\rho$ is a character on $A$, and let $\tau$ be a positive linear functional on $A$ such that $\tau\leq\rho$. If $\rho(a)=0$, then $ \rho(a^*a)=0$, so $\tau(a^*a)=0$. Since $|\tau(a)|\leq\tau(a^*a)^{1/2}$, therefore $\tau(a)=0$ (*via an application of Cauchy-Schwarz*). Hence, $\text{ker }\rho\subset\text{ker }\tau$, and it follows from elementary linear algebra that there is a scalar such that $\tau=t\rho$

*Choose a $a\not\in\text{ker }\rho$. Now for all $b\in A$, we have
$$\rho\left(b-a\frac{\rho(b)}{\rho(a)}\right)=0.$$
Now we can write
$$b=\left(b-a\frac{\rho(b)}{\rho(a)}\right)+a\frac{\rho(b)}{\rho(a)};$$
that is $A=\{c+\lambda a:c\in\text{ker }\rho,\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\}$ with $\rho(c+\lambda a)=\lambda \rho(a)$. Suppose $\text{ker }\rho\subsetneq\text{ker }\tau$. Now choose an $a\in\text{ker }\tau\backslash\text{ker }\rho$. Now any $b\in A$ is of the form $b=c+\lambda a$, with $c\in\text{ker }\rho$ and $a$ as above:
$$\begin{align}\Rightarrow \tau(b)&=\tau(c)+\lambda(a)=0+\lambda 0=0
\\\Rightarrow\tau&=0.\end{align}$$
If $\tau$ is non-zero we therefore have that $\text{ker }\rho=\text{ker }\tau$. Now
$$\begin{align}\tau(b)&=\tau(c)+\lambda \tau(a)=0+\lambda \tau(a)
\\&=\lambda \rho(a)\frac{\tau(a)}{\rho(a)}=\underbrace{\frac{\tau(a)}{\rho(a)}}_{:=t} \rho(b).\end{align}$$
In other words, $\text{dim }A/\text{ker }\rho=1$.*

Choose $a\in A$ such that $\rho(a)=1$. Then $\rho(a^*a)=1$, so $0\leq\tau(a^*a)=t\rho(a^*a)=t\leq\rho(a^*a)=1$, and therefore $t\in[0,1]$. This shows that $\rho$ is pure and the equivalence   is proved $\bullet$

Comment: Thanks, but I can not any difficulty with this proof. As I mentioned I would like to know why Murphy shows $\langle uv x,x\rangle = \langle ux,x\rangle \langle vx,x\rangle$ for $u,v\in B(H)$, in which case it's just sufficient to show the equality for $\phi(a),\phi(b)\in \phi(A)$.